# winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 7.0.0.0~focal-1) E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages

Tags: wine

I read this solution before to ask but it don't solve for me

https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?t=36119

I got this error and seems that is unsolvable

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 7.0.0.0~focal-1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

**Note**: I use Ubuntu 20.04 LTS x64 from Vultr cloud

Comment: Unless you have a specific need for the latest version of wine that is required to run a specific application, undo everything you have done and install the version from the Ubuntu 20.04 repos. Do not follow any instructions on web pages about how to install wine.